# Having an issue with wp_nav_menu displaying custom navigation

Tags: menus

Below is the HTML menu structure I would like to display with `wp_nav_menu`:

```
<ul class="right-top">
    <li><a href="#">Join Now</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">English <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu right-menu">
            <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Second</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Third</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fourth</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I can add a 'dropdown' class with the function below, but I don't know how to add a class for the anchor & data-toggle attribute:

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'add_menu_parent_class' );
function add_menu_parent_class( $items ) {
    $parents = array();
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        if ( $item->menu_item_parent && $item->menu_item_parent > 0 ) {
            $parents[] = $item->menu_item_parent;
        }
    }
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        if ( in_array( $item->ID, $parents ) ) {
            $item->classes[] = 'dropdown';
        }
    }
    return $items;
}
```

I also need to add a class for the sub menu ul: `<ul class="dropdown-menu right-menu">`

Comment: Are you using `Bootstrap`?

Comment: yes.. i got the HTML as it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Bootstrap, implementing WordPress menu is a bit tricky. It needs a Custom Walker Menu class to be implemented.

Here's a complete tutorial how you can implement a WordPress Nav Menu with Bootstrap:

- [How to Integrate Bootstrap Navbar Into WordPress Theme](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-integrate-bootstrap-navbar-into-wordpress-theme--wp-33410) by *Kateryna Belyaeva*

The Custom Walker Class can be found here on GitHub:

- [wp-bootstrap-navwalker - Github](https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker) by Edward McIntyre

But on this integration, please note:

The following code block is important, where we are accepting only 2 level of the menu. The Bootstrap 3.0 developers choose the max level of a navbar menu to be 2 level deep.

```
<?php /* Primary navigation */
    wp_nav_menu( array(
      'menu' => 'top_menu',
      'depth' => 2,
      'container' => false,
      'menu_class' => 'nav',
      //Process nav menu using our custom nav walker
      'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
    );
    ?>
```

If you want multilevel menu, then Edward also provided a technique for Bootstrap 2.3.2 with multi-level support:

- [Multilevel Bootstrap Navbar](https://gist.github.com/twittem/6022669) - Gist by Edward McIntyre

Comment: Thanks a lot.. great solution :) Really appreciate your help.